# jquery-mobile dialog without hash change

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile. I want to open a dialog containing external page as content. At the same time not want to change hash in url.

I have link
Open dialog
which opens the dialog but changes the hash in url. Need help, thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official docs:

> Since dialogs are typically used to support actions within a page, the
>   framework does not include dialogs in the hash state history tracking.
>   This means that dialogs will not appear in your browsing history
>   chronology when the Back button is clicked.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/

Comment: thanks for the info Grigno, but I don't want to have '#&ui-state=dialog' in url when the dialog opens. And also if # is already in url then the dialog not opens, can you give some information regarding this.